# Datastax Python cassandra driver build fails on Ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, ubuntu, cassandra

I was trying to install Datastax Python Cassandra driver on Ubuntu 14.04.5. LTS. Installation succeeds but subsequent attempt to use it fails with the error:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-91-generic x86_64)
~$ python3 --version
Python 3.5.2
~$ python3 -c 'import cassandra; print(cassandra.__version__)'
3.7.0
~$ python3 cassandra_loader.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cassandra_loader.py", line 7, in 
    from cassandra_tools import transform_record, QueryManager
  File "../lib/cassandra_tools.py", line 6, in 
    from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
  ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cassandra/cluster.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: PyException_Check
```

same installation process and same code works well on RedHat. Google search for error code returns nothing. Anybody has an idea of what could be the issue?

Comment: I too am facing the same issue in production. Observed this Warning while building the driver:


    cassandra/cluster.c:16461:7: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘PyException_Check’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
           __pyx_t_15 = PyException_Check(__pyx_v_f);
           ^

Comment: We have the same issue, it first occurred 12 hours ago or something, we are using Python2.7 though

Comment: https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/PYTHON-656 workaround is mentioned here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is duplicate of this question: [cluster.cpython-34m.so: undefined symbol: PyException_Check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40257850/cluster-cpython-34m-so-undefined-symbol-pyexception-check/)

I answered it there but here is copy of the answer as I can't comment.

---

Latest version of Cython (0.25) released today broke cassandra-driver.

Workaround for this issue it to install Cython==0.24.1 before installing cassandra-driver.

`(env) $ pip install Cython==0.24.1
(env) $ pip install cassandra-driver`

You may need to remove existing cassandra-driver package first from site-packages:

`rm -r $WHERE_PYTHON_IS_INSTALLED/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cassandra*`

See https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/PYTHON-656 for more information

Answer (score 1):

We just released a patch version 3.7.1 to fix that issue caused by the new version of Cython. Upgrade your cassandra-driver:

```
    pip install --upgrade cassandra-driver
```

Comment: I'm using the cassandra-driver via django-cassandra-engine==0.11.1 (http://r4fek.github.io/django-cassandra-engine/) and am getting this error with 3.7.1: `cassandra.cqlengine.CQLEngineException: Connection name '<object object at 0x7f47b75b1740>' doesn't exist in the registry`.  It was working fine with cassandra-driver==3.6.0.  Not really sure if the problem is mine, django-cassandra-engine, or cassandra-engine; still looking into this.

Comment: Pinning Cython down to 0.24.1 as suggested above and keeping the Cassandra version at 3.6.0 worked for me.