# cluster.cpython-34m.so: undefined symbol: PyException_Check

Tags: python-3.x, cassandra, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, datastax

I am running a simple python(3.4.3) flask app on amazon linux, which uses datastax cassandra-driver(3.6). My application is failing to import the module.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "application.py", line 12, in <module>
    from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
ImportError: /opt/python/run/venv/local/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/cassandra/cluster.cpython-34m.so: undefined symbol: PyException_Check
(venv)[ec2-user@ip-1-1-1-1 app]$ uname -a
Linux ip-1-1-1-1 4.4.15-25.57.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Jul 27 22:37:49 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Other Packages installed:
$ pip freeze
cassandra-driver==3.6.0
click==6.6
Flask==0.11
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.8
MarkupSafe==0.23
six==1.10.0
Werkzeug==0.11.11
xmltodict==0.10.2
```

Comment: I have the same issue today, and probably I am not the only one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40251893/datastax-python-cassandra-driver-build-fails-on-ubuntu - this question was created today as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Latest version of Cython (0.25) released today broke cassandra-driver.

Workaround for this issue it to install Cython==0.24.1 before installing cassandra-driver.

`(env) $ pip install Cython==0.24.1
(env) $ pip install cassandra-driver`

You may need to remove existing cassandra-driver package first from site-packages:

`rm -r $WHERE_PYTHON_IS_INSTALLED/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cassandra*`

See https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/PYTHON-656 for more information

Comment: Hi Menth, The woraround resolve the issue. But I am getting new errors. By chance can this be related? [Wed Oct 26 16:04:00.590289 2016] [:error] [pid 29365] [remote 1.1.1.1:62755]     raise CQLEngineException("%s.cluster is not configured. Call one of the setup or default functions firs
t." % __name__)
[Wed Oct 26 16:04:00.590311 2016] [:error] [pid 29365] [remote 1.1.1.1:62755] cassandra.cqlengine.CQLEngineException: cassandra.cqlengine.connection.cluster is not configured. Call one
of the setup or default functions first.

Comment: VaibhavJain: I have not seen that error before. Did you forget to actually call setup function? Try this: 
`from cqlengine import connection
connection.setup(['127.0.0.1'], "cqlengine")`

Comment: Menth, look like some other problem. I can connect to cassandra from the shell but somehow my app on aws bs throwing this error.