# Cassandra python driver - undefined symbol

Tags: python, cassandra, aws-lambda

I am trying to run the python Cassandra driver on AWS lambda. I followed the [amazon guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html) on how to build the deployment package with the cassandra-driver dependency. I still cannot get it work because of this error:

```
Unable to import module 'login': /var/task/cassandra/cluster.so: undefined symbol: PyFPE_jbuf
```

I found another [S.O. question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40251893/datastax-python-cassandra-driver-build-fails-on-ubuntu) related to this issue, in which is stated that driver version 3.7.1 solves the problem (and that can be confirmed [here](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/PYTHON-656)), however I am still getting it.

Is anyone having the same issue running the python driver on aws lambda?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone is experiencing the same issue, after many attempts, I solved it building the package using an EC2 instance running the Amazon Linux AMI.

I don't know actually the exact reason, but pip via virtualenv was not generating the **lib64** folder on my laptop (Ubuntu 16.04), which I got instead on the EC2 instances and that has been populated with additional files while installing the **cassandra-driver** package and related dependencies (futures, six).